# Configuring a formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Below is a screenshot of my data:

[image]

What will be the formula for counting the total number of enrollments for each insurance plan example: The total number of enrollments for "AARP MedicareComplete SecureHorizons (HMO)" is 1818. I have tried `=COUNTIFS(Jan!C2:C,"AARP MedicareComplete SecureHorizons Value (HMO)",Jan!G2:G,)`

Comment: Where do you want to insert the result? In every "Total_Enrollments" cell so that if it appears 3 times in a row you will have the same total each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Jan!B2:B; "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''")
```